# How to better manage Qualys WAS for 30 sites that are scanned monthly

Tags: security

Hello everyone: I was giving the responsibility of a Qualys WAS. There are around 30 sites I need to monthly scan, and check alerts. I need to automate all this process so I'm thinking on this

1- Create an script or application that could easily schedule and start the scan of the sites

2- The same app will also pull the reports from Qualys WAS

Now it comes to the issue:

I need to report on the issues found. And have those reports where they could be accessible for compliance reasons.

I'm assuming a lot of other security engineer here have the same issue. So my question is what do you do about this?

I was thinking about what to do and thought that these could be some options, but I want to hear from people that have already faced the same issue:

Is the best option to create an application that pulls the issues found from Qualys and later, presents them in a system or DB, with a web interface easy to be validated and share with people who need to access that info?
Is there any system that already solve my issue(see above in black), that maybe we can buy?
Could you talk about your experience with this?
I have another question. Do you think that having 30 sites, scanned monthly, validating issues found, and doing some other administrative stuff to keep this part working as perfect as possible, do you think just one skilled engineer is enough 100% on this? Or do you think I will need to ask for more people?

Thanks

Comment: You can export the Qualys results in csv, then use bug tracking like Jira to get all scan results in one place, sort in categories, and track them.

Comment: So using the Qualys API I can get the results in CSV and then pull them to Jira , all these programmatically. Do you think JIRA will be a good place to then analyze the alert and put my annotations? So let say if I get than an alert is a false positive I will close the Jira item if it is indeed a issue that require remediation , then I will move it to developers/infrastructure queue in JIRA? Do you think it is a good flow ?

Comment: Jira can't analyze the "vuln" itself, but it can do all you are expecting, sorting, severity, categorizing by systems/apps and assigning to the appropriate teams, then tracking all the to remediation.

Comment: Yes sorry If I did not express clearly. I will do the analysis. Do you know what module or part or API or subsystem in JIRA will I be able to upload the csv containing the scan results?

Comment: Try this link https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/importing-data-from-csv-938847533.html

Comment: Yes, definitely this is really close to what I need. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Kapish M for his response

In order to help the community and anyone who faces the same issue, I will post here an answer but will leave the question open just in case some else have other options.

Qualys has no connector/plugin, for direct JIRA integration but  API can make any similar integrations possible.  While downloading data from Qualys via API, most times it is NOT very possible to make this communication 2 way unless the other vendor (JIRA etc) be willing to do it.

So it is possible to take one of these two routes to solve this issue:

1- Look for a 2-way integration system, like Service Now, that should make possible to integrate the system much more easier. Today, ServiceNow has 2-way integration.

2- Take care programmatically of 
    - Downloading Qualys report in CSV format
    - Modify the CSF format to adapt it to JIRA as per [2]
    - Analyze the issues in JIRA and move the ticket to other groups or close them

3- Because of the high demand of integration of this Security Tool, Qualys has created a Qualys-JIRA integration whitepaper available in [3]

Took information for this answer from:

[1]-[Importing CSV into Jira](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/importing-data-from-csv-938847533.html)

[2]-[Qualys integration](https://discussions.qualys.com/thread/19262-integration-with-jira-ticketing)

[3]-[Qualys Jira integration whitepaper](https://discussions.qualys.com/docs/DOC-6911-custom-qualys-jira-integration-whitepaper#jive_content_id_Custom_QualysJiraIntegration_Whitepaper)